# Show $\mathcal{R}(A) \supseteq \mathcal{R}(B) \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{rank} A = \mathrm{rank} (A | B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I need help to prove:

> Given two matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$. The following equivalence is true:
> $$
> \mathcal{R}(A) \supseteq \mathcal{R}(B)
> \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
> \mathrm{rank} A = \mathrm{rank} (A | B).
> $$
> $\mathcal{R} (\cdot)$ denotes the image of a matrix and $(A | B)$ is a matrix with the columns of $A$ and $B$ next to each other.

I don't really know how to start with the proof. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rank(A)$ is the dimension of $\mathcal{R}(A)$, which is the span of the columns of $A$. Since $\mathcal{R}(B)\subset\mathcal{R}(A)$, the columns of $B$ are in the span of the columns of $A$, so the dimension of the column space does not increase when you attach $B$ to $A$. Hence the rank does not change.

The reasoning can be reversed. The rank is unchanged as long as you add columns which are linear combination of the previous ones.